# Getting blank error exception message while adding data to the mysql table

Tags: c#, mysql

the code below is self explanatory. I have 16 input sources(textboxes , comboboxes,etc) on a form and I want all those inputs to go into a mysql table I created , called submissiontable. I have only pasted the parts necessary and not the whole 550 lines of code

```
public partial class Form1 : System.Windows.Forms.Form
{
     static string conString = "Server=localhost;Database=Work;uid=root;Pwd=password";
     MySqlConnection mson = new MySqlConnection(conString);
     MySqlCommand mcd;
     MySqlDataAdapter adapter;
     MySqlDataReader rdr;
     DataTable dt = new DataTable();

     private void btn_submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
          if (checkBox1.Checked)
          {
               submit(txt_empid.ToString(), txt_empname.ToString(), txt_mgrid.ToString(), txt_mgrname.ToString(), txt_phno.ToString(), txt_emailid.ToString(), txt_dept.ToString(), txt_circle.ToString(), txt_rqst_type.ToString(), txt_pol_period.ToString(), txt_bj.ToString(), txt_chngtype.ToString(), txt_sod.ToString(), txt_destapp.ToString());
          }
          else
                    MessageBox.Show("Agree the terms and conditions");
      }

     //Submit
     private void submit(string empid, string empname, string mgrid, string mgrname, string empph, string empmail, string empdept, string empcircle, string rqsttype, string polperiod, string busjur, string chngtype, string sodno, string destapp )
     {
          //sql stmt

          string submitdb = "INSERT INTO submissiontable(empid,empname,mgrid,mgrname,empph,empmail,empdept,empcirlce,rqsttype,polperiod,buisinessjuris,chngtype,sodno,destapp) VALUES(@eid,@enam,@mgid,@mgnam,@ephone,@email,@edept,@ecirc,@reqtyp,@polprd,@busjur,@chtype,@sodno,@dapp)";
          mcd = new MySqlCommand(submitdb, mson);
                 mcd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@eid", empid);
                 mcd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@enam", empname);
                 mcd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mgid", mgrid);
                 mcd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mgnam", mgrname);
                 mcd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ephone", empph);
                 mcd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", empmail);
                 mcd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@edept", empdept);
                 mcd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ecirc", empcircle);
                 mcd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@reqtyp", rqsttype);
                 mcd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@polprd", polperiod);
                 mcd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@busjur", busjur);
                 mcd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@chtype", chngtype);
                 mcd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sodno", sodno);
                 mcd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dapp", destapp);
          //OPEN MSON[CON] AND EXEC INSERT
          try
          {
                mson.Open();
                if (mcd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
                {

                        MessageBox.Show("Submitted Successfully");
                }
                mson.Close();
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    MessageBox.Show("test");
                    mson.Close();
          }
      }
```

screenshot of db:[image]
[image]
Create query , as requested :

```
CREATE TABLE `submissiontable` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `empid` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `empname` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mgrid` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mgrname` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `empph` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `empmail` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `empdept` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `empcircle` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rqsttype` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `polperiod` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `buisinessjuris` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `chngtype` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sodno` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `destapp` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),

) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Why does the insert operation not work? I placed a messagebox in the catch section to confirm that the error is in the try section [as a messagebox with test popped up]

Comment: Could you, please, *format out* your code? Especially *sql parameters*.

Comment: christ that indentation is awful. normally I'd fix it myself, but I just can't bring myself to do it for this one.

Comment: Please check your column names that mysql error suggests that you are trying to insert values in column that does not exist, maybe a typo somewhere in the query ?

Comment: I checked it thrice , but I'll check it again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error 1054 for sql is basically unknown column . So kindly check if all the columns mentioned in your INSERT query are also there in your table "submissiontable".

If they are there kindly get back to me with the create query of your table .

Thank you

Thankyou for posting your db

if the id column in your db is not auto generated ..you will have to specify its value in the insert query as it cannot be null according to your db

Column name empcircle is different in insert query ..
change it from empcirlce to empcircle

Comment: yes , all of them are there [except ID] I have posted the snap of the db above

Comment: I have put it on autoincrement in column properties and as the primary key...the default value is blank as I can't change that

Comment: wow how did I not see that...thank you so much ! but sadly now I am gettin a blank error message [followed by the 'test' messagebox] , which means there is still an issue in the try method . Let me try and get back to you after some of my own attempts

Comment: nope. tried many things. mostly making changes to the id column ,but to no avail.still that blank error exception message

Comment: can you show the error message as it is...cause i tried creating your table and inserting with your query ...and it does work

Comment: How do I get the error message? I use visual studio which shows no error message. There is just one pop up which is empty. The mysql log is empty...

Comment: in that pop there will be a message on top .copy paste that or if possible kindly take screenshot

Comment: There isn't. I'll post a snap and you can see for yourself

Comment: added snap . please check it out

Comment: Do you have any clue?

Answer (score 3):

Well, MySQL error 1054 stands for unknown column. It means that in your insert statement you used a column name that does not exists in your table. The error message itself will tell you more details about which column name may cause the error. Interpret the error message and fix the column name issue.

Based on spelling, I think `buisinessjuris` is a good candidate for a typo issue.

Comment: I know that was a horrible , horrible choice for a coloumn name , and I checked it multiple times because of that. You may see the screenshot of my db in the question

Comment: The error message will tell you the name of the column that is missing. Sorry, I'm not going to compare the list of columns in the insert with the list of columns in a picture, that's sg for you to do. Also note, that the error may be related to  fat that MySQL interprets part of the sql statement as a column name, while you meant to use it as data.

Comment: I don't want you to do that. I have already done it and have posted the snap just so people can confirm on certain issuse (like with buisinessjuris). And what do you mean by "to fat that MySQL interprets part of the sql statement as a column name, while you meant to use it as data."?

Comment: Why don't you check the exact error message, for God's sake! MySQL will tell you what column name it could not find!

Comment: Don't you think if i did get an error message besides "unknown error#1054" , I would have come here or at least that I would not tell  about it in the question? All I get is a messagebox with "unknown error#1054". that is all. I can press the submit button a 100 times and i'll get the same result each time

Comment: Get the **MySQL** error message. It does return the column name, not just the error code. Pls do proper debugging.

Comment: there ya go. added a screenshot of the error message so that you may see the possibility of "proper debugging"

Comment: Check out the various properties of your exception object, study the MySQL tutorials on .net exception handling because MySQL does provide a meaningful error message for this type of error and the MySQL exception class does return the full error message. Your exception handling code is not correct if you do not get the full error message back.

Comment: I honestly can't see this code being any different from my previous SQL insert queries, which worked. The exception code is right in front of you. I have checked it and you may check it too. I don't see anything that can cause any issue. I am using mysql on wamp server. I checked the mysql log and was empty

Comment: All these are totally irrelevant. You need to check your exception code to get the full MySQL error message, not just the error code.